# Custom vectorized non-linear filter in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, vectorization

In digital image processing, many filters are non-linear, such as Harmonic Mean Filter.

I know in Numpy, they provided many vectorized functions which could speed up the computing time tremendously, but currently I have not known any that could work well with non-linear masks.

In specific, I want to speed up the calculation of my implementation of the above filter, which removes two ugly, snail-paced Python `for` loops:

```py
import math as m

def harmonic(im, ksize):
    # Make a copy of the original image
    result = im.copy().astype(np.float32)

    # Calculate padding size, and pad the original image
    psize = m.floor(ksize/2) # paddding size
    im = cv.copyMakeBorder(im, psize, psize, psize, psize, cv.BORDER_REFLECT)

    # Perform non-linear operations
    for i in range(0, result.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, result.shape[1]):
            # Get the neighborhood same size as kernel
            neighbor = im[(i):(i+2*psize+1),(j):(j+2*psize+1)].astype(np.float32)
                        
                        # ----------------------------------------

            # Calculate the reciprocal sum
            recp_sum = np.sum(np.reciprocal(neighbor,where= neighbor != 0).astype(np.float32))

            # Harmonic mean for that neighborhood
            if (recp_sum != 0):
                result[i][j] = (float((ksize*ksize)/(recp_sum)))

                        # ----------------------------------------
    return result.astype(np.uint8)
```

In general, could we utilize Numpy to create any custom vectorized operations on a array? Or only a limited number operations and what types are they? If yes, what could I do specifically to optimize the above code?

I have tried to explore Numpy vectorization recently, and `np.vectorize` really caught my attention. However, the examples provided on the documentation was a bit (as far as I feel) irrelevant to the problem I am trying to solve. (English was not my native language so I may miss something, I'd be happy to be elaborated!)

Related to `np.vectorize`, I do not really understand `pyfunc` param. Does it really eliminate the traditional Python loops wrapped in that `pyfunc`? Or it's there just to define a specific mapping at a specific pixel in the array?

Comment: just use numba. no, plugging numpy primitives together has limits

Answer (score 2):

The harmonic mean is the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of the reciprocals. That is,

```py
tmp = 1 / im.astype(np.float32)
tmp = cv2.blur(tmp, (ksize, ksize))
out = 1 / tmp
```

You might want to add a bit of code there to avoid division by zero. The simplest way is to replace zeros with very small values.